# is json.loads() the fastest way to convert a string to a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, performance, dictionary

I'm trying to quickly convert a string to a dictionary.  json.loads() seems to be > 10 faster than eval().  I have also tried ast.literal_eval() and yaml.loads() which are also much slower.  Are there any quicker options?  Could a custom C++ function implemented via cython be much faster or is json.loads() mostly optimized already?

```
import time, json
msg = '[{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":12,"bp":432.55,"ap":432.56,"bs":6,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114456090,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":10,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":1,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455883,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":8,"ax":10,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":1,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455887,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":10,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":1,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455888,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":10,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":2,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455890,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":2,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455895,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":3,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455901,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":8,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455907,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":9,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455917,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":6,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455918,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":19,"ax":12,"bp":432.55,"ap":432.56,"bs":7,"as":2,"t":1643310960406,"q":114456110,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":11,"ax":12,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.55,"bs":3,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455919,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":11,"ax":21,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.56,"bs":3,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455921,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":21,"bp":432.54,"ap":432.56,"bs":6,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455924,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":10,"ax":21,"bp":432.55,"ap":432.56,"bs":5,"as":1,"t":1643310960406,"q":114455933,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":8,"ax":12,"bp":432.55,"ap":432.56,"bs":7,"as":2,"t":1643310960407,"q":114456132,"z":1},{"ev":"Q","sym":"TODAY","c":1,"bx":8,"ax":12,"bp":432.55,"ap":432.56,"bs":9,"as":2,"t":1643310960407,"q":114456134,"z":1}]'

start = time.perf_counter()

for n in range(0,1000):
  msg2 = json.loads(msg)
end = time.perf_counter()

print(end-start)
```

Comment: Under no circumstance do you ever want to use `eval` for this situation.  You are opening a big security hole in your program.  To quote Tony Hoare, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  I'm finding it hard to believe that converting a string to a dictionary is the time-critical piece of your application.

Comment: And personally, I'd use `ast.literal_eval()`.  It's the one intended to interpret Python strings as Python in a safe manner.

Comment: It actually is the time-critical element.  ast.literal_eval() takes 425ms per 1000 messages with the data I provied, wheras json.loads takes around 24ms.  I am processing well over 1000 messages per second on average and when it would burst above 3000 messages per second the eval() function was too slow, as would be ast.literal_eval()

Comment: Okay.  This really is the time critical piece of your code.  Is the server actually sending JSON (most do these days) or is it sending a Python string?  Python strings are more expressive that JSON.  But if the server is sending JSON, or if its restricting itself to the subset of Python that JSON understands, you should be okay.

Comment: If you can use a fact that this string has some repetitive structure, as in the provided example, then for sure it is possible to make faster solution. `json.loads()` has to deal with all possible json structures and can't use such "exploit" as you (possibly) could.

Comment: `json.loads` is not the fastest way. But the actual question is how far you are ready to get to optimize this since the optimized code can be far more complex. That being said, the thing is this function takes a lot of time creating Python objects and all super-fast parsing will be bounded by this resulting in a small speed-up. Thus, do you actually need to create the dict of just extract some fields? And what do you do with these fields/dicts. Creating/Deleting several hundred thousands ref-counted objects serially takes a bunch of time (especially on servers often working at <3 GHz).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Do you think there's something faster than `msg2 = msg.split('"')`? Doesn't do the job, just does something similar, and seems only a bit more than twice as fast.

Comment: @KellyBundy The split is quite efficient but creating string objects take a lot of time. `msg.split('$')` is ~15 times faster. Python lists are quite fast to create in built-in functions. Dicts are slower to create due to string hashing and indirections+resizes. This is why extracting only some fields could help. Note that using an opaque dict-like type that does not create Python objects internally should prevent this overhead. So yes, it is probably possible to design something faster, but definitively not much if the output is the one of `json.loads`.

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Yes, yes, creating that large number of string objects, about as many as `json.loads` produces, was intentional. I meant that as somewhat of a limit, for how fast we cant possibly be able get what `json.loads` produces. Showing that `json.loads` is at least *almost* optimal at that.